# Error while using iterator mediator in wso2esb

Tags: loops, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2esb 4.7.0 and wso2dss 3.1.0.My scenario is i wish to select all partybranch regarding particular clientid. For that purpose i have fire a query like :

```
select partybranchid,clientid from mpartybranch where clientid = 473906852857651
```

and it gives me list of 2 records like :

```
partybranchid    clientid

-2500000000      473906852857651
796243010946586  473906852857651
```

I wish to split these two and find out address regarding each of them.I have use following query in dss that works seperately for me is :

```
select * from address where partybranchid = ? and clientid =?
```

Now i have use iterator mediator in wso2esb to implement this in single click.My configuration is :

```
     <iterate xmlns:f="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" continueParent="true" preservePayload="true" expression="//f:Datalist" id="iterate1" sequential="true">
        <target>
           <sequence>
              <property xmlns:s="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" name="partybranchid1" expression="//s:partybranchid/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
              <property xmlns:s="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" name="latitude" expression="get-property('latitude')"/>
              <property xmlns:s="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" name="longitude" expression="get-property('longitude')"/>
              <property xmlns:s="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" name="radius" expression="get-property('radius')"/>
              <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                 <format>
                    <p:select_addresses_op xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                       <p:latitude>$1</p:latitude>
                       <p:longitude>$2</p:longitude>
                       <p:radius>$3</p:radius>
                       <p:objectid>$4</p:objectid>
                    </p:select_addresses_op>
                 </format>
                 <args>
                    <arg xmlns:s="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" expression="get-property('latitude')" evaluator="xml"/>
                    <arg xmlns:s="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" expression="get-property('longitude')" evaluator="xml"/>
                    <arg xmlns:s="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" expression="get-property('radius')" evaluator="xml"/>
                    <arg xmlns:s="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" expression="get-property('partybranchid1')" evaluator="xml"/>
                 </args>
              </payloadFactory>
              <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
              <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
              <send receive="spatial_seq3">
                 <endpoint>
                    <address uri="http://localhost:9764/services/Aspatialtrial_Dataservice/" format="soap11"/>
                 </endpoint>
              </send>
           </sequence>
        </target>
     </iterate>
```

This configuration is working but doesn't give expected output.Following are the outputs at client side and server side:

At server side(ESB) output :

```
[2014-09-25 09:52:30,941]  INFO - LogMediator To: /services/spatial_proxy_test, MessageID: urn:uuid:c91c22b6-245f-49f7-bf30-65561c87050f, Direction: request, userid = null, username = vikash|214057357158656, password = gbadmin
[2014-09-25 09:52:30,953]  INFO - TimeoutHandler This engine will expire all callbacks after : 120 seconds, irrespective of the timeout action, after the specified or optional timeout
[2014-09-25 09:52:31,286]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:9fa3c017-27f5-405e-a11b-33a9fa9a8f44, Direction: response, kk = true, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><ResponseJSON><Body><Datalist><Authentication>true</Authentication></Datalist></Body></ResponseJSON></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2014-09-25 09:52:32,148]  INFO - LogMediator FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT = true, partybranchid1 = -2500000000796243010946586, latitude = 18.975, longitude = 72.8258, radius = 10
[2014-09-25 09:52:32,344]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:c635aa03-36ac-4af7-8b01-9bb31b35f4ef, Direction: response, Datalist values logged = <Datalist xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"><addressid>457492199890748451</addressid><geocode>POINT(18.975 72.8258)</geocode></Datalist>, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><DataCollection xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"><Datalist><addressid>457492199890748451</addressid><geocode>POINT(18.975 72.8258)</geocode></Datalist></DataCollection></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2014-09-25 09:52:32,345]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:e77556c0-b722-4f91-879b-1cbb4ae20aec, Direction: response, Datalist values logged = <Datalist xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"><addressid>456211760366486560</addressid><geocode>POINT(19.0769048 72.8570555)</geocode></Datalist><Datalist xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"><addressid>456217678470710306</addressid><geocode>POINT(18.975 72.8258)</geocode></Datalist>, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><DataCollection xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"><Datalist><addressid>456211760366486560</addressid><geocode>POINT(19.0769048 72.8570555)</geocode></Datalist><Datalist><addressid>456217678470710306</addressid><geocode>POINT(18.975 72.8258)</geocode></Datalist></DataCollection></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

at client side output

```
{"ResponseJSON":{"Body":{"Datalist":{"addressid":"457492199890748451","geocode":"POINT(18.975 72.8258)"}},"Status":"200","Total":"1.0"}}
```

And request is :

```
 curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "ModifiedOn:0"   -H "username:vikash|214057357158656" -H "password:gbadmin" -d '{"usercode":"suresh","clientid":"473906852857651","longitude":"72.8258","radius":"10","latitude":"18.975"}' http://youtility-desktop:8282/services/spatial_proxy_test
```

Server side log shows that it is iterating fine but at client side gives response of one iteration only.Why so?IS their any changes regarding sequence options like ContinueParent or preservepayload etc..?Please let me know..

Comment: Could you share the request/response SOAP message in ESB and in AS/DSS? Also after the payloadfactory you can print the partybranchid property value.

Comment: Hi Jorge Infante Osorio.Thanks for reply.I have removed errors from my configuration.Now it's working but not in expected manner.Will you please tell me why so? i have edited my question .Please refer above

Comment: Please check my answer, in my scenario work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I test your scenario last night, my proxy look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="AddressProxy"
       transports="https http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property xmlns:p="http://www.example.org/Address/"
                   name="clientid"
                   expression="//p:getAddress/clientid"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <sequence key="conf:/sequencesStackOverFlow/getmpartybranch"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <aggregate>
            <completeCondition>
               <messageCount min="-1" max="2"/>
            </completeCondition>
            <onComplete xmlns:add="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"
                        expression="//add:Addresses/add:Address">
               <send/>
            </onComplete>
         </aggregate>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL key="conf:/wsdls/Address.wsdl"/>
</proxy>
```

And the sequences used in the insequence:

conf:/sequencesStackOverFlow/getmpartybranch

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
      <format>
         <dat:getmpartybranch xmlns:dat="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">            
            <dat:clientid>$1</dat:clientid>         
         </dat:getmpartybranch>
      </format>
      <args>
         <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="get-property('clientid')" evaluator="xml"></arg>
      </args>
   </payloadFactory>
   <send receive="conf:/sequencesStackOverFlow/iterOvermpartybranch">
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://127.0.0.1:5555/services/mpartybranch"></address>
      </endpoint>
   </send>
</sequence>
```

conf:/sequencesStackOverFlow/iterOvermpartybranch

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <iterate xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" expression="//ds:DataCollection/ds:Datalist" id="iterate1" sequential="true">
      <target>
         <sequence>
            <property name="partybranchid" expression="//ds:partybranchid/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"></property>
            <property name="clientid" expression="//ds:clientid/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"></property>
            <log>
               <property name="PARTYID" expression="get-property('partybranchid')"></property>
               <property name="CLIENTID" expression="get-property('clientid')"></property>
            </log>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
               <format>
                  <dat:getselect_addresses xmlns:dat="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">                     
                     <dat:objectid>$1</dat:objectid>                     
                     <dat:clientid>$2</dat:clientid>                  
                  </dat:getselect_addresses>
               </format>
               <args>
                  <arg expression="get-property('partybranchid')" evaluator="xml"></arg>
                  <arg expression="get-property('clientid')" evaluator="xml"></arg>
               </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <log level="full"></log>
            <send>
               <endpoint>
                  <address uri="http://127.0.0.1:5555/services/getAddress" format="soap12"></address>
               </endpoint>
            </send>
         </sequence>
      </target>
   </iterate>
</sequence>
```

You need to use the aggregate mediator to collect the responses and create one unique message to return to the client. Check my outsequence. In my case I just need to use the transformer mediator to change my payload according to the WSDL.